# Pure Javascript alternatives to toggling a CSS class?

Tags: javascript, html, css

My goal is to rotate a div 180deg on each click, without toggling CSS classes.

I can achieve one rotation with the first click (.style.transform = 
            "rotate(180deg)";), but any subsequent click has no effect.

BTW, why exactly is that? The div's Id hasn't changed, so, in theory, the same trigger (a click, in this case) should call the same function, right? But it doesn't. I wonder what's the logic here, what's the technical explanation, and, moving to practice, how can I further manipulate this post-div (that is, the original div after its JavaScript manipulation) -- again, without toggling CSS classes.

```js
function rotate() {
    document.getElementById("container").style.transform = 
    "rotate(180deg)";
}
```

```css
.container {
    width: 200px;
    height: 400px;
    border: 5px solid;
    border-bottom-color: blue;
    border-top-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" id="container" onclick="rotate()"></div>
```

Comment: [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList): `containerElement.classList.toggle("animate")`

Comment: It only works once because the transform is not **increased** on each click.

Comment: Toggling an HTML class (class attributes are not part of CSS) is the *good* approach. It gives you separation of concerns and useful debugging hints in the DOM.

Comment: Store the rotation in a data-attribute, increase it on each click and set the style basing on that value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the transform value and then rotate it anti-clockwise.

Here is the code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container" id="container" onclick="rotate()"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
    width: 200px;
    height: 400px;
    border: 5px solid;
    border-bottom-color: blue;
    border-top-color: red;
}
```

**JS**

```
function rotate() {
    document.getElementById("container").style.transform = 
      document.getElementById("container").style.transform === 
    "rotate(180deg)" ? "rotate(0deg)" : "rotate(180deg)";
}
```

Here is an example in [codepen](https://codepen.io/shubham2307/pen/agLmwP)

Answer (score 5):

The first time you change the transformation from `""` to `"rotate(180deg)"`, so it rotates.

Subsequent times you change it from `"rotate(180deg)"` to `"rotate(180deg)"` … which isn't a change at all, so nothing happens.

If you want to change it, then you need to actually assign a *different* value to it.

e.g.

```
const style = document.getElementById("container").style;
if (style.transform) {
    style.transform = "";
} else {
    style.transform = "rotate(180deg)";
}
```

Toggling a class is simpler, and clearer.

```js
document.querySelector("#container").addEventListener("click", e => e.currentTarget.classList.toggle("rotated"));
```

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 5px solid;
  border-bottom-color: blue;
  border-top-color: red;
  transition: transform 0.25s;
}

.rotated {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container" id="container"></div>
```

Comment: @Ruedi.Angehrn — No, but there isn't even a suggestion that that is a requirement in the question. My statement was about the problem present, not a hypothetical one that's vaguely related to it.

Comment: Well your comment kinda reads like a global statement "Toggling an HTML class (class attributes are not part of CSS) is the good approach. It gives you separation of concerns and useful debugging hints in the DOM".

Comment: @Ruedi.Angehrn — That comment (on the question, not this answer) was, again, given in the context of *this problem*.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the div is not rotating after first function call is that you are setting the transform style property to constant value (180deg). After first call the transform is performed and all following calls set transform to exactly the same value. In order to make it work, you have to increment rotate property each time you call the function.

In example:

```
let rotation = 0;

function rotate() {
    document.getElementById("container").style.transform =  `rotate(${rotation}deg)`;
    rotation = (rotation + 180) % 360;
}
```

Comment: I dislike this approach since it merely works as long as I have exactly one image to flip (due to having one unassociated variable containing the rotation).

Answer (score 1):

I made a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/um72fpxy/) , but basically, you can't rotate for the same value. Of course this is very raw, but prove the concept for you to understand. You can do it more programatically of course.

```
document.getElementById('container').addEventListener('click', function () {
  this.style.transform = this.style.transform == "rotate(180deg)" ? "rotate(-90deg)" : "rotate(180deg)";
  }
);
```

You can check this out: [tutorial](https://www.quackit.com/css/functions/css_rotate_function.cfm)

Comment: Why are you assigning `obj` if it has to be `this`?

Comment: What is the problem? Just to be clear what we are referencing. There is nothing wrong with it.

Comment: It is not wrong, but totally unnecessary. Both the assignment and the refetching. `obj` has to be `this` in your example. So no need to make another `getElementById()` for it. Also your logic would fail if I assigned this listener to multiple elements which I wanted to rotate the same way.

Comment: Op asked for just one div. Like i said, this is a very raw example and could be improved programmatically. But thanks for your notes on optimizing code.

Comment: Why downvote? The code does exactly what op asks for. There people here trying to optimize answers, this is not what this site is for.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
var degrees = 0;
function rotate() {
  if(degrees == 180){
    document.getElementById("container").style.transform = 
      "rotate(360deg)";
    degrees= 0;
  }else{
    document.getElementById("container").style.transform = 
      "rotate(180deg)";
    degrees= 180;
  }       
}
</script>
```

Clearly is not optimized but could help you.

JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ot9wq6mk/)

Comment: The use of the variable `degrees` is pointless in this example. Also it does not really seem to toggle back on a second click (your fiddle does not match the answer here).

Comment: Yes, I noticed.

Answer (score 0):

Others have answered your question already, so I will provide with an example to make your code a little bit more dynamic.

```js
/**
* Rotate an <element> with a certain angle <rotateBy>
* 'this' is a reference to itself, which is passed by as an argument from the HTML.
* Change '180' in the method call to whatever to have it rotate differently.
*/

function rotate(element, rotateBy) {
  var currentRotation = element.rotation || 0;   // default to zero if not existing
      newRotation = rotateBy + currentRotation;

  element.rotation = newRotation;  // store the property in the element

  element.style.transform = "rotate(" + newRotation + "deg)";
}
```

```css
.container {
    width: 200px;
    height: 400px;
    border: 5px solid;
    border-bottom-color: blue;
    border-top-color: red;

    transition: transform 400ms;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" onclick="rotate(this, 180)"
></div>
```